# Use of PUSH and POPD in windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a requirement where I need to run a batch script which would compile a custom module and then come back to the project's root location and run the project.

For this, I have written something like below

```
SET curDir=%~dp0
PUSHD %curDir%
echo %curDir%
cd modules\custom-module
yarn build
POPD
echo %CD%
yarn start
```

but after the `yarn build` command, it stays in the `modules\custom-module` directory.

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `pushd /?` and read the output help. Then run in same cmd window `popd /?` and read again the output help. Replace in your batch file the first four lines by `PUSHD "%~dp0modules\custom-module"` to push current directory (can be different to batch file directory) on stack and set the specified directory as current directory. `POPD` restores initial current directory.

Comment: Is `yarn` really `yarn.cmd`, running `@node "%~dp0\yarn.js" %*`?

Comment: In case `yarn` is another batch file, you ***have to*** call it - and better always use the extension `call yarn.bat build` / `call yarn.cmd build`

Answer (score 0):

Before changing the directory call 'setlocal'. So your script will look like following

```
cd                            <- prints current dir
setlocal
cd modules\custom-module
yarn build                    <- if yarn is script, do 'call yarn build' instead
endlocal
cd
yarn start
```